# Do any editions of Chronicles of Narnia use the publication order numbering?

Tags: suggested-order, the-chronicles-of-narnia, publishing

It seems that nearly everyone online suggests to read the *Chronicles of Narnia* in its original intended publication order (see for example [the answers on this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15841/what-order-should-the-chronicles-of-narnia-books-be-read-in)), but it also seems that the series is only ever published in chronological order.

Are there any editions that use the original numbering?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first several "boxed set" editions all used publication order. I grew up, for example, with the [Collier editions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00146LW0G). [Wikipedia strongly implies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia) that the first publisher to use the in-universe chronological order was Harper Books (now HarperCollins), when they acquired rights to the series in 1994. I have seen a set of the books published under the Fontana Lions imprint (owned by HarperCollins) appearing in this order; various references date this edition to the early 1980s.

Since at least the mid-90s if not before, this in-universe chronological order seems to have become the standard order in which the publisher produces all sets (including a single-volume edition I've found).

Comment: What is "this" in "this was the only order used"?

Comment: @tashus "this order", the chronological order.

Comment: My Fontana Lions set of paperbacks from 1980 are numbered in chronological rather than published order

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! I'll see if I can find an instance of those to refer to.

Comment: @horuskol I did find a fairly clear picture of these online, displaying the series order, and it is indeed as you say - and there are references to publication dates in the early 1980s. But apparently (per Wikipedia at least) Fontana is not a publisher but an imprint of HarperCollins. I'll note the possible new date.

Comment: Yeah, from the book "Fontana Lions is an imprint of Fontana Paperbacks, a division of the Collins Publishing Group"

Answer (score 4):

While not strictly the book series (and not as universally acclaimed), the Walden Media [film adaptations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia_(film_series)) have so far been released in publication order - *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe* in 2005, followed by *Prince Caspian* in 2008, followed by *The Voyage of the Dawn Treader* in 2010. The 1988 [British TV series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia_(TV_series)) also uses publication order, beginning with *Lion* in 1988 and following with *Caspian*, *Dawn Treader*, and finally *The Silver Chair*. It should be noted that neither of these adaptations includes *The Magician's Nephew* or *The Horse and His Boy*, which are the two books published out of chronological order.

Comment: The 1998 TV serialisation also followed publication order.

Comment: *1988...  only just spotted the typo.

Comment: This is probably the one example of the movies being better than the books. That at least they're in order.

Answer (score 0):

Not new ones. You can find older editions in the correct order on used book websites, and probably in used book stores. Anything published in the last 25 years or so uses the revised order.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by citing specific examples of editions that used the original numbering (and preferably not editions already named in previous answers, so as to avoid making this answer redundant).

Comment: Or, I could write the answer I wrote which responded to the question asked, unlike the other answers. Being a pedantic jerk doesn't make you sound smart.

Comment: [Matt Gutting's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/226243/122024) noted that the first several boxed set editions all used publication order and that everything published since the mid-'90s uses the in-universe chronological order. Your answer appears to say the essentially same thing and nothing more, which means it isn't currently adding any new information to thread.